# Maven enterprise application run with -1.0 in the end

Tags: java, maven, glassfish

Sometimes when i run my **maven web application**, the application run with **-1.0** in the end, and this make a problem, is there any explanation of this problem, and how we can solve it.

Normal url : http://localhost:8080/projectmvn-web

Wrong url : [http://localhost:8080/projectmvn-web-1.0](http://localhost:8080/projectmvn-web)

I use server **glassfish-3.1.2** and **Netbeans 8.1**.

EDIT:

**application.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" version="6">
    <description>description..</description>
    <display-name>projectmvn-ear</display-name>
    <module>
        <ejb>projectmvn-ejb-1.0.jar</ejb>
    </module>
    <module>
        <web>
            <web-uri>projectmvn-web-1.0.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>/projectmvn-web</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>
    <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `1.0` is the project version in your `pom.xml` file, if you don't have the `build` element in your `pom.xml` add the following as a child of `project` element:

```
<build>
   <finalName>projectmvn-web</finalName>
</build>
```

If you already have the `build` element add the `filalName` element as follows:

```
<build>
   <finalName>projectmvn-web</finalName>
   // the rest goes here
</build>
```

With this setting Maven should create `projectmvn-web.war` in the `target`folder, i.e., without the version information on the filename.

Comment: Thank you @ujulu for your answer, this should help me

Comment: where should i put this configuration in the ear or web pom.xml?

Comment: Put it in the web pom.xml.

Comment: One question: what is the content of `application.xml` file in the ear module?

Comment: If the application is deployed as an `.ear` on a server you don't need to change the `pom.xml` file because the application is already configured correctly in the `application.xml` file: `<context-root>/projectmvn-web</context-root>` already did it. It is only if you want to remove the `-1.0` suffix from the `war` file you need to modify the `pom.xml` in the web module.

Comment: so what should i do now, you don't think it is a problem of cache, because when i restart netbeans and delete my project from .m2 every thing is correct, so i think it is just a problem of cache i'm wrong??

Comment: I cannot tell you if netbeans is caching because I don't have any experience with it; but I would still modify the pom, remove the content of `.m2/repository` directory, and build the project (mvn clean install) and no version information should be on the name of the war file, and even if it caches it will be that same name as the `context-root`s value.